# Estilização por props não funciona

Tags: javascript, css, react

estou aprendendo react e tentei passar uma estilização por props, mas não vejo o resultado no navegador. Gostaria de deixar o `<p>footer<p/>` mais para baixo, então dei uma customClass, porém não funciona. Alguém tem ideia do que pode ser?

App.js

```
import { Nav } from "./Components/Nav";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route,Routes} from 'react-router-dom'
import { Home } from './Components/pages/Home';
import { Company } from './Components/pages/Company';
import { NewProject } from './Components/pages/NewProject';
import { Contact } from "./Components/pages/Contact";
import { Container } from "./Components/layout/Container";
 
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Nav/>
      <Container  customClass="minheight" >
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/company" element={<Company/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/contact" element={<Contact/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/newproject" element={<NewProject/>} />
        </Routes>
      </Container>
      <footer>Footer</footer>
    </Router>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

Container.js

```
import styles from './Container.module.css'
export function Container (props){
    return(
        <div className={`${styles.container}${styles[props.customClass]}`}>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Container.module.css

```
.Container{
    width: 1200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin:0 auto;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
/*
Este minheight deveria fazer com que o footer ficasse bem para baixo
*/
.minheight{
    height: 75%;
}
```

Comment: acho eu sem testar: `${styles.container}${styles[props.customClass]}` está muito junto não deveria ter um espaço: `${styles.container} ${styles[props.customClass]}`

Comment: Perfeito cara, Muito obrigado.